I am having difficulties adding MDBottomNavigation to Kivy App
I'm trying to add a MDBottomNavigation to a screen but I'm just not understanding how it works. I've tried following https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.1/components/bottomnavigation/index.html tutorial in vain. Your help will be highly appreciated.
Here's what I've tried:

MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    MDScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        
        MDScreen:
            name: "home_page"

            MDBottomNavigation:
                selected_color_background: "white"
                text_color_active: "orange"

                MDBottomNavigationItem:
                    name: "home"
                    text: "Home"
                    icon: "home"
                    on_tab_press: app.root.ids.screen_manager.current = "home_page"


<HomeScreen>:

    name: "home_page"

    # more code

<SettingsScreen>:
    
    name: "settings_page" 

    # more code

My Python file
class HomeScreen(MDScreen):
    pass

class SettingsScreen(MDScreen):
    pass        

class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        
        self.theme_cls.material_style = "M3"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        
        return Builder.load_string(kv)
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()


Many thanks in advance.
